# Why does arcpy.da.SearchCursor() class not autocomplete within Eclipse?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, eclipse

I am very new to GIS.

I just installed eclipse luna with pydev plug-in and ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

When I write a script, trying to import arcpy.da.SearchCursor I see that no SearchCursor is available to autocomplete.

[image]

What is the problem? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SearchCursor` is a class in the `arcpy.da` module and not a module itself, so if you wanted to import just that class you could use:

```
from arcpy.da import SearchCursor
```

You could then reference it as just `SearchCursor`.

You can also import the entire module and reference the class within, and it's also worth noting that `import arcpy` automatically imports `arcpy.da` and a bunch of other arcpy related things.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have discovered that the import arcpy and arcpy.da.SearchCursor works even if the Eclipse underline that with red line O.o

Comment: @gregtom6 you need Forced builtins for arcpy.da  . Go to Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter > Forced builtins. Click on New... and add **arcpy.da** has value. Finaly apply change and all will work

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten that worked for me, minor typo correction, you enter arcpy.da *as* value. (I only mention it because I was momentarily confused and thought the entire entry was "arcpy.da has value", which was more due to my inexperience with Python in Eclipse). Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking that also explains why pylint always tells me "Module 'arcpy.da' has no 'UpdateCursor' member"

Answer (score 17):

I don't think the original poster was asking about how to use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`, but rather that the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` class was not appearing in the code completion window within Eclipse (sometimes called intellisense or [intelligent code completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion)).

I've been using Eclipse+PyDev and/or [LiClipse](http://www.liclipse.com/) for editing code for geoprocessing tools since ArcGIS 10.1 came out, and I have **never** been able to get code completion for any `arcpy.da` modules. There are a few posts about this on the Esri GeoNet (formerly Esri forums), see [one](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/50853), [two](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/30797), and [three](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/45715). In thread one, [Dave from Esri says](https://geonet.esri.com/message/257945#257945) (emphasis mine):

> The overriding goal for the data access module was speed.  As I'm sure you're aware the older cursor model wasn't nearly as fast.  As part of that, **arcpy.da doesn't have the Python wrappers that provide the dropdown's that you see in most of arcpy**.  Essentially, it was a trade-off between speed and IDE-friendliness, and in this case the criterion dictated speed trump.

So unfortunately, there's no way to get Eclipse's nice code completion for the `da` module. However, you can still avoid the annoying red `Undefined variable from import: SearchCursor` error in Eclipse by putting `#@UndefinedVariable` at the end of the line, like so:

```
MyCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("MyLayer",["*"]) #@UndefinedVariable
```

Comment: Exactly this. It's a pure CPython implementation with no Python source wrapping it, so most IDEs can't interrogate it for autocomplete.

Comment: Yey, I now understand, and I will take this as is.

Comment: Great explanation, Dan - thank you for summarizing and providing a band-aid :)

Comment: Adding "#@UndefinedVariable" works for me, Thank you :) Funny thing, though. Adding a 2nd ".da" to the text: "arcpy.da.da." awakens the code completion in PyDev (Eclipse Luna), but causes execution error, even with "#@UndefinedVariable".

Comment: @dmahr i fact that is not really true. You can just add arcpy.da in force builtins pannel for completion.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by adding 'arcpy' and 'arcpy.da' to my 'Forced Buitins' tab for my Arcpy Python Interpreter in eclipse. Code completion works and it no longer marks things like da.SearchCursor as an undefined variable.

Comment: Following this and @GeoStoneMarten's suggestion above is what worked for me.