# Pycharm cannot find reference 'SearchCursor' in 'arcpy.da'

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, cursor, pycharm

Whenever I try to use a search cursor from arcpy in pycharm, I get this unresolved reference error. I should note that it was working fine earlier in the night, I have no idea what happened.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I've tried everything in this Q&A already:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code

Other arcpy functions seem to work fine. I've also tried restarting computer and reinstalling pycharm. I can use the search cursor when I use IDLE.

Comment: Does this stop your scripts from running, or is it just the IDE telling you it can't find it for the auto-complete?  My Visual Studio 2013 also doesn't find SearchCursor etc. but I'm still able to complete the code and everything runs fine.

Comment: Have you looked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/how-to-setup-pycharm-to-reference-arcpy?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it does work despite the message. I didn't even think to try it. Thanks!

Comment: To get rid of the message you can add a comment line to ignore the inspection:

            # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences

            mycursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields, where_clause)

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of 'Setting up PyCharm to reference ArcPy?'. arcpy.da classes are not visible in PyCharm or other IDE by default even arcpy is referenced. Please see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120335/why-does-arcpy-da-searchcursor-class-not-autocomplete-within-eclipse/120517 to get idea what it is about and how to sort out this issue in Eclipse IDE. Vote to reopen this question!